# LinkedList why do we have to create the dummy here?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I am new to solving the algorithms related to the data structures and I'm unsure of the following code I encountered the question:

```
public ListNode swapPairs(ListNode head) {
    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
    dummy.next = head;

    head = dummy;
    while (head.next != null && head.next.next != null) {
        ListNode n1 = head.next, n2 = head.next.next;

        head.next = n2;
        n1.next = n2.next;
        n2.next = n1;                   
        head = n1;
    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

Why do we have to create the dummy here?

It would be of a great help if you could help me out on this. I have observed similar steps when you have to perform some operation on the linked list.

Comment: Where did this function come from? Is there a definition of what `swapPairs()` is supposed to do? We can't tell you why it written a certain way without knowing what the expected behavior is..

Comment: Hi, this is the question. Please have a look at it. Thanks.                                                                      Given a linked list, swap every two adjacent nodes and return its head. For example, Given 1->2->3->4, you should return the list as 2->1->4->3. Your algorithm should use only constant space. You may not modify the values in the list, only nodes itself can be changed.
Java

Comment: It makes the code inside the loop simpler. Otherwise every time you changed a node you would have to worry about whether it was the head or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Makes things clear now. Do we use this approach when we have to make some changes to the particular linked list such as deleting a particular node or some other operations? Also, is it appropriate to call "n1" and "n2" as pointers here? I know the concept of pointers doesn't exist in java, but what would be an appropriate name for these variables while trying to explain in interviews?

Comment: It's appropriate when you may be altering the head node. Pointers do exist in Java, otherwise there wouldn't be a `NullPointerException`: however they are pointers in the Pascal sense, not the C sense. A pointer is either null or an object reference. But in an interview you might be safer calling them references, as interviewers aren't always as knowledgeable as they should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Appreciate it...

Comment: For my understanding, you are shifting the head pointer twice each time in while loop, but you need to return the result list node. So you define a dummy node(0) as start point and declare its next to head, and importantly that what you changed in while loop on head node will not affect dummy point position.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to swap two nodes in a linked list, you need to change the `next` pointer in those nodes *and* the preceding node.

For example, you have a list `A->B->C`, and you want to swap `B` and `C`, you need to change the `next` pointers in *all* of those nodes.

If you want to swap the *first* two nodes, however, then you need to change the `next` pointers in those two nodes *and* the pointer to head of the list.

So, the stuff you have to do depends on whether or not you're swapping at the beginning of the list...  But the author of your function is lazy, and he didn't want to have to write two different kinds of swap code.

Mr. Lazy programmer therefore stuck in a dummy node before all the stuff he has to swap.  That way he doesn't have to swap anything at the beginning and he can use the same code for all swaps.  He removes this node at the end so no harm is done.

Creating a dummy node is not that expensive in Java, but I would not have done it this way.

I would write out the two ways like this:

```
public ListNode swapPairs(ListNode head) {
    
    if (head != null && head.next != null) {

        //swap first 2 nodes
        ListNode n1 = head;
        ListNode n2 = n1.next;

        head = n2;
        n1.next = n2.next;
        n2.next = n1;                   
        ListNode pred = n1;

        //swap remainder
        while (pred.next != null && pred.next.next != null) {
            n1 = pred.next;
            n2 = n1.next;

            pred.next = n2;
            n1.next = n2.next;
            n2.next = n1;                   
            pred = n1;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: All programmers should be lazy. I would say this is a good solution.

Comment: @EJP programmers should carefully pick and choose what they're lazy about.  My code is not a lot longer, doesn't require a question on SO to understand, and it's fast no matter what other stuff might be inside a ListNode.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans, great solution, but this line `if (head != null || head.next != null)` should be with `&&`, otherwise it could return Null pointer exception.

Answer (score -2):

Adding dummy node is not necessary at all. In Fact, you're changing the head of linked list by adding dummy node as head. Your code should work without dummy node.

```
public void swapPairs(ListNode head) {

    if(head!=null) {
      while (head.next != null && head.next.next != null) {
        ListNode n1 = head.next, n2 = head.next.next;

        head.next = n2;
        n1.next = n2.next;
        n2.next = n1;

        head = n1;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer..could you please tell me a situation where adding nodes would be helpful. Thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't add a dummy node as head, and this code doesn't return the new head. It also appears to lose most of the list.